# The setup for Tensorflow with GPU on Windows 11 does not work

Tags: windows, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to set my computer to run Tensorflow on GPU, according to the instructions here: https://quark-mushroom-28d.notion.site/Tensorflow-with-GPU-on-Windows-11-70893cc80d1b457e90384f4acaa78a2b, but it does not seem to work.

I tried the steps listed in the Notion doc above, but I get "[]" when running python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))", although I am using a laptop with a NVIDIA 3050 Ti video card.

It would be great if someone could help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Start by reading the documentation, specially the warning about Windows: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native_1 Also your link to Notion does not work.

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Snoopy! I started with the link you mentioned, but no luck. Apologies, I corrected my link.

Comment: Did you read the link I gave? Seems not, because the version of TensorFlow you are trying does not support GPU on Windows natively. So what you are trying will never work. Please read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the version of your current cuda drivers and the version of cuda drives you have installed on your gpu?
Below is the link for documentation have a look at the version
[TF Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Also I would suggest you using linux for more support of TF